# Get BPM of song in iOS

Tags: ios, spotify

I am using Spotify to play songs in my iOS app, and I need to get additional data such as BPM and song familiarity. Where can I get this? I have searched for it but not really found anything good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For data that the Spotify metadata API does not provide, I suggest using [Echonest](http://echonest.com/). It has a lot of cool data about a lot of songs, including familiarity.